# Unable to publish chrome extension on Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am unable to upload a screenshot to my chrome extension dashboard in Web Store. Everytime I upload any image, an error prompts 'Image size is incorrect'.

I have tried every possible way to tackle this -
1] Uploaded the correct pixel dimension (1200*800 or 600*400 JPEFG or 24 bit png)
2] Compressed the screenshot in order to reduce the size of the file (I thought maybe 'incorrect size' refers to the file size)

Comment: Please test this. [1280x800.jpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1amSA51GbhBak0fkMWadarjCVgBUuehx6/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: The correct size for the screenshots for CWS is 1280x800 or 640x400 JPEG or 24-bit PNG (no alpha)

Comment: @IvánNokonoko I have tried the specified image dimensions. The error is still the same.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I was able to upload this image successfully. What is that I am doing wrong? How do I convert a screenshot to such a dimension (1200*800px)? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: 1280*800 is the correct resolution, not 1200*800.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto Thank you very much for helping me out. It feels so dumb of me to ignore such a thing. Thanks again.